# $\det(ABC) = \det(BA^{-1}C^{T}A^{2})$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A$,$B$,$C$ three square matrices. Then I have to show that $$\det(ABC) = \det(BA^{-1}C^{T}A^{2})$$

I would start with the left side and proceed by rearranging and using some properties:
\begin{align}
\det(BA^{-1}C^{T}A^{2}) 
&= \det(B)\det(A^{-1})\det(C^{T})\det(A^{2}) \\
&= \det(B)\det(A)^{-1}\det(C)\det(A^{2}) \\
&= \det(A)\det(A)\det(A)^{-1}\det(B)\det(C) \\
&= \det(A)\det(B)\det(C)
\end{align}

Is this proof correct?

Comment: Not only "would": it is correct. Of course, you're willingly using the product theorem, right? +1

Comment: Yeah I am. I just used properties which were given during the lecture, thus, i am allowed to use it without proofing them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

(I'm assuming that by "$*$" you mean multiplication. That ought to be notated as $\cdot$ or juxtaposition).